# Some email not delivered using ROR(ruby on rails 3) production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Some email not delivered using ROR(ruby on rails 3) production environment.
We are using  apache + passsenger to run our application on all development and production environments.
We are trigger some email on X actions on our site. on dev server all email are currently delivered properly. but Somehow production some email are not delivered to the recipient.

we are using gmail as smtp.
production log says that email has been out from server and render the html on server 
Below is the log 
The rails log also shows the mail being sent without any issue.

Rendered user_mailer/warehouse_daily_orders_email.erb (538.7ms)
Sent mail to abc@gmail.com (2890ms)

Rendered user_mailer/warehouse_daily_orders_email.erb (0.1ms)
Sent mail to abc@gmail.com (1536ms)

Rendered user_mailer/warehouse_daily_orders_email.erb (0.1ms)
Sent mail to abc@gmail.com (1753ms)

Rendered user_mailer/warehouse_daily_orders_email.erb (0.2ms)
Sent mail to abc@gmail.com (30013ms)

Answer (score 1):

You should handle this deliver procedure in background.
Why don't you use `delayed_job` to deliver mail?

[Here is a tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job) on **RailsCast** to implement this.

It'll resolve your problem.

Comment: i have tried that here is  the log status 
2014-01-17T11:13:07+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Starting job worker
2014-01-18T08:00:32+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Job Class#warehouse_daily_orders_email (id=1) RUNNING
2014-01-18T08:00:35+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Job Class#warehouse_daily_orders_email (id=1) COMPLETED after 2.0887

Comment: yes the log is saying every thing is working fine. But email not receive to the recipient that the main problem. there is nothing to me for debug but email not received.